# How to include more than one other table using Sequelize?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I have the following tables:

```
Product:
name: string, description: string, image: string

Brand:
name: string

Category:
name: string
```

One Product can only have One Brand.
One Product can have multiple Categories.

My associations are:

```js
models/product.js:
Product.associate = function(models) {
    Product.hasOne(models.Brand, {
      foreignKey: "productId",
      as: "brand"
    }),
      Product.hasMany(models.Category, {
        foreignKey: "productId",
        as: "categories"
      });
  }
```

```js
models/category.js:
Category.belongsTo(models.Product, {
      foreignKey: "productId",
      onDelete: "CASCADE"
    })
```

```js
models/brand.js:
Brand.belongsTo(models.Product, {
      foreignKey: "productId",
      onDelete: "CASCADE"
    })
```

1- is it OK so far? The indentation in models/product.js seems odd to me.

2- in my Products controller, how do I retrieve both the brand and the categories of my products?
Currently I have:

```js
controllers/products.js:
list(req, res) {
    return Product.findAll({
      include: [
        {
          model: Category,
          as: "categories"
        }
      ]
    })
      .then(products => res.status(200).send(products))
      .catch(error => res.status(400).send(error));
  }
```

Categories are included, how do I also include the brand?

I expect the output to be an array of products that all contain a brand and one or more categories.

Answer (score 2):

Given the established associations, you should be able to add the other model, comma-delimited, like so:

```
controllers/products.js:
list(req, res) {
    return Product.findAll({
      include: [
        {
          model: Category,
          as: "categories"
        },
        {
          model: Brand,
          as: "brand"
        }
      ]
    })
      .then(products => res.status(200).send(products))
      .catch(error => res.status(400).send(error));
  }
```